# How to change the default mode of "reset" to "hard" in Tortoisegit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

For my project environment, I prefer to use hard mode to execute a reset.

Any config files needed to be edited?

Comment: just an advice : `git reset --hard` is one of those few destructive commands in git, which can silently remove content from your disk without providing a way to get it back. I would advise to live with the extra click on the `--hard` checkbox, to keep the barrier to an accidental "hard reset" on your current code.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand the source code for the "Reset" dialog in [`src/TortoiseProc/ResetDlg.cpp`](https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/blob/8009b870f1e97c92ce668245cd4a171b50ac815e/src/TortoiseProc/ResetDlg.cpp), the initial selection for the radio button is hard coded as 1 which means `--mixed`, so there is no way of configuring it.

> ```cpp
> CResetDlg::CResetDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=nullptr*/)
>     : CHorizontalResizableStandAloneDialog(CResetDlg::IDD, pParent)
>     , CChooseVersion(this)
>     , m_ResetType(1)
> {
> }
> ```

This has been [added in 2009](https://github.com/TortoiseGit/TortoiseGit/commit/a2c8b7d75cd39285cd1e65b3e0bb10a3ae849c33) and has never been changed since.

Answer (score 2):

As of TortoiseGit 2.12 there is no way to change the default of the reset mode.

Performing a hard reset by mistake also is likely to result in a data loss.